# Getting responsive Javascript menu to stack under img.

Tags: javascript, html, css

After multiple tries with this problem I now need some help from you. I have created a menu system with a logo. My struggle is that the menu will not stack under the logo when @media reaches 823px. Anyone who sees a solution to my problem?

Code and CSS could be found on this codepen https://codepen.io/Daxtux/pen/zJLgBX

```
<a href="#news"><img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo" style="float:left;width:110px;"></a>
<div class="Navigasjon" id="Toppnavigasjon">
<a href="#news">MENY 1</a>
<a href="#Howto">MENY 2 </a>
<a href="#about">MENY 3</a>
<a href="#about">MENY 4</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
</div>
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could add     padding-top: 50px;  to the   . Navigasjon   when screen is max-width 823px

Answer (score 0):

So you want the hamburger menu int he top right corner to be clicked and then the menu appear beneath the logo? My first question would be why not just keep it beneath the logo all the time.

But ignoring that, my suggestion would be to put the logo and header all in one containing div, then use `display: flex;` or `display: grid;` to set them up so they fall the way you want htem.

For example if you made the container `width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content:space-between;flex-wrap: wrap;` Then put `min-width: 450px;` on each child element, the children would automatically wrap to the next line anytime the container was less than 900px in width.

You could do something similar using display:grid; by changing the `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` to `grid-template-columns: 1fr;` at the smaller media query size.